# Pros and Cons of localization based on a key or on the actual string

Tags: web, localization, client, client-server

I am interested to find good pros and cons on implementing localization based on keys or the actual strings.

With keys, the implementation is a function where the parameter is a key for that string:

`translate(DeleteFileConfirmationId)`

With actual strings, the implementation is a function where the parameter is the actual string of the default\neutral language:

`translate('Are you sure you want to delete the file?')`

The issue I see with the latter is if the application needs to display a different element (for example, an image) based on the value returned from the backend, if the value is a string and not a key, it has to check with the string:

```
if(x === 'Red dragon') 
{
    displayImage('RedDragon.png');
}
```

The con side of the 1st approach is that everything has to be translated and all the values returned from backend must use keys. Which is not necessarily bad, but the 2nd approach gives more flexibility.

Any other pros and cons?

Comment: It is easier to change the text of the default language (e.g. there is a typo) with the first implementation. having hard coded output message seems like a bad idea if it can be avoided

Comment: Thank you. I corrected the typo (I think). I've seen many, many people using the 2nd approach. I also prefer the 1st approach.

Comment: I updated with a con side of the 1st approach.

Comment: I wasn't implying that there was a typo in your post ;-). I wanted to say 'IF there is a typo in the text string in default language, and you need to edit it, it would be more complicated with the second approach'. And many people use the second one probably because of laziness at first time.

Comment: Arghh :) I see what you mean now. I'm trying to figure out if I am missing something, maybe their "laziness" has a point. Sometimes being lazy has some unexpected good results :) Or maybe they have a point, it's not because they're lazy.